# Hyper-V 2012 R2 - multiple public IP mapping

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, nat

I have a physical server with Windows 2016 Datacenter and Hyper-V activated.
Multiple VMs are configured and need to be reached from the Internet.

My provider assigned multiple public IPs on the physical server and do not allow me to assign them directly in the virtual machines settings.

He asks me to create NAT rules from Hyper-V guest and VMs.

What I already did:
- I created a new virtual switch on the guest and assign it "192.168.1.1/24"
- I assigned the 3 public IPs to the "Internet" adapter of my physical server, in addition to its own public IP

Here is a diagram to explain what I want to do :

[image: diagram]

**Can you please tell me how can I do that? If it's not possible with Windows 2016, can I do that with Windows 2012 R2?**

Comment: Hyper-V in Windows Server 2012 R2 doesn't support NAT. Take a look at the accepted answer on this question for a solution - http://serverfault.com/questions/821859/configuring-nat-on-a-hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a way with the "Remote access" mmc console.

Comment: To make this a useful answer for others, please add details.

Comment: Very interested in knowing how you did it.